# Jest tests leaking due to improper teardown

Tags: node.js, testing, redis, jestjs, bull

While doing testing with Jest I am getting a warning saying "A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks." I realize that this is coming because inside of one of functions I use Bull https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull which uses Redis. So when adding a task to the queue it results in this warning. I use default Bull configuration (no configuration). I do have a mockup for the add function on the queue which is used by Jest, however it didn't help.

```js
const notificationQueue = {
  add: jest.fn().mockImplementation((data: any, opts?: JobOptions) => {}),
};
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to avoid this warning. If it helps I use in memory mongo for testing but redis is an actual one. As a side note when I run each test suite separately I am not seeing this warning, only when I run all tests.

Answer (score 48):

As suggested in the warning, add `--detectOpenHandles` option to jest's script in package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll --detectOpenHandles"
  }
```

Dont forget to **stop** then **start** the server !

This solution can work whatever your problem. But, according to your case, your problem is coming from **the redis connection**. *You need to close redis at the end of the test*:

```
import { redis } from "redis_file_path";

afterAll(async () => {
    await redis.quit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Issue is `mongoose.connect()` I simply mocked the mongoose connection

```
import { app } from "../src/index";
import request from "supertest";

jest.mock('mongoose')

describe("routes", () => {
  it("should pass", async () => {
    const response = await request(app).get("/hello");
  });
});
```